# Reading a table with blank cells with tabula-py

Tags: python, pandas, tabula-py

I am trying to load a large table (an example is attached) from form 10-K into Python using tabula-py.  The table does not have clear border, and have a lot of blank cells, which cause several issues.

My code is

```
df = tabula.read_pdf("firm_xxx_10K.pdf", pages='100-101',guess=True,stream=True,columns=(144,210,300,340,380,420,450))
```

With `stream=True`, I get all the data, but the information in multiple rows are recognized as separate entries.  With `lattice=True`, then the cells with multiple rows are correctly recognized as one cell, but now the results miss a lot of observations.

Is there a better way to set the options?  I tried many options, but now I am stuck.  Any help is much appreciated.
Best,

[Example of the Table I am Trying to Read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8HWd.png)